# Redmine to Easyredmine, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm trying to upgrade from redmine to easyRedmine following this doc: 
https://www.easyredmine.com/resources/installation/234-redmine-upgrade-to-easy

I get an error while migrating plugins, the error is :
ActionView::Template::Error (The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'ContactCustomField'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite EasyPageModule.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.)

I found this : https://www.easyredmine.com/knowledge-base?view=knowledge_detail&id=166&category_id=64#maincol

It's true that i've deleted the plugins files directly, i reinstalled them again and i uninstalled them right, and still have the problem. However on the link i provided there is the part of editing from the rails console, but i've no idea how to do that, any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

To start rails console login to your server, navigate (**cd /var/www/redmine** for example) to the folder where your Redmine installation resides, and type:

```
rails c production
```

It will start your rails console where you can perform various tasks, as described in link you provided within question.